# Dynamically loading CSS

Tags: javascript, css, ajax

I'm trying to create a page theme function for my site. I want to load the corresponding themes dynamically on the page using separate CSS files.

I'm using this code:

```
  fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet")
  fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css")
  fileref.setAttribute("href", 'link.css')

  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref)
```

Which works fine, but it doesn't return any info if the CSS file has loaded or not.

Is there a way to catch when the `.css` is loaded? Maybe by using ajax?

Comment: see useful link here http://www.cssnewbie.com/simple-jquery-stylesheet-switcher/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Internet Explorer will trigger an `onReadyStateChange` event when CSS file is loaded (or any other change in it's `readyState`).
Other browsers do not trigger any event, so you will have to manually check if the stylesheet has been loaded, which is easily possible by checking the `document.styleSheets` object at a fixed interval.

**Example**

```
window.onload = function (){
    var filename = "link.css",sheet,i;
    var fileref = document.createElement("link");

    fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
    fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
    fileref.setAttribute("href", filename);

    readyfunc = function () {
        alert("File Loaded");
    }

    timerfunc = function (){
        for (i=0;i<document.styleSheets.length;i++){
            sheet = document.styleSheets[i].href;
            if(sheet !== null && sheet.substr(sheet.length-filename.length) == filename)
                return readyfunc();
        }
        setTimeout(timerfunc,50);  
    }

    if (document.all){ //Uses onreadystatechange for Internet Explorer
        fileref.attachEvent('onreadystatechange',function() {
            if(fileref.readyState == 'complete' || fileref.readyState == 'loaded')
                readyfunc();
        });
    } else {    //Checks if the stylesheet has been loaded every 50 ms for others
        setTimeout(timerfunc,50);
    }
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref);    
}
```

It's ugly, but it works in all browsers.

Comment: Thanks! Haha, you're right about it being ugly, but it does the job.