# Load css by date with javascript

Tags: javascript, css, date

I'm looking to load different css files according to the date (season).

I tried modifying an image script from here on stackoverflow, but that didn't work.

Can anybody point me out where it goes wrong?

```
<link href="/css_season/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" onload="logo(this)">
```

```js
function logo(link) {
  var d = new Date();
  var Today = d.getDate();
  var Month = d.getMonth();
  var src;
  if (Month === 4 && (Today >= 1 && Today <= 30)) {
    src = "/css_season/easter.css";
  } else if (Month === 7 && (Today >= 1 && Today <= 31)) {
    src = "/css_season/vacation.css";
  } else if ((Month === 8 && Today >= 30) || (Month === 0 && Today <= 2)) {
    src = "/css_season/vacation.css";
  } else if (Month === 12 && (Today >= 15 && Today <= 31)) {
    src = "/css_season/holidays.css";
  } 
  link.href=href;
}
```

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744270/dynamically-loading-css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assignment `link.href=href` won't work because `href` isn't defined. Also, I would put the `logo` function in `<body onload="logo();">` and give your `link` tag an id attribute.

This should work for you:

```
<html>
<head>
<link id="cssId" href="/css_season/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body onload="logo();">
 <!-- body content here -->
</body>

function logo() {
  var d = new Date();
  var Today = d.getDate();
  var Month = d.getMonth();
  var src;
  if (Month === 4 && (Today >= 1 && Today <= 30))
    src = "/css_season/easter.css"; 
  else if (Month === 7 && (Today >= 1 && Today <= 31))
    src = "/css_season/vacation.css";
  else if ((Month === 8 && Today >= 30) || (Month === 0 && Today <= 2))
    src = "/css_season/vacation.css";
  else if (Month === 12 && (Today >= 15 && Today <= 31))
    src = "/css_season/holidays.css";

  document.getElementById('cssId').href=src;
}
```

Comment: Another argument for placing `onload` on the `body` instead of the `link`: [many browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/link#Browser_compatibility) don't support `onload` on `link` (yet). Still, there's room for improvement: you could stop using the `onload` attribute entirely and attach a `load` event handler inside the script itself (separating HTML from JavaScript); also you could place all styles in one CSS file and let JavaScript place a class on the `body` (instead of changing the loaded CSS) to distinguish between styles.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick and accurate response ! I will check out and respond.

Comment: Just to be sure, I probably can add <script type="text/javascript"> and </script> around the javascript?

Comment: This `<script>` and `</script>` around the Javascript will do.

Comment: I tried the script, but there seems to be an error, nothing happens. Could it be conflicting with other jquery on the page? What is the structure to load several jquery best to have no conflicts?

Answer (score 1):

You have wrong assignment at the end of the js function.
`link.href=href;` should be `link.href = src;`

Cheers