# Javascript listener to capture URL of currently loading resource

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Is there any way to capture URLs of currently loading resource in javascript. For example, if browser starts downloading a JS, CSS or IMG file then is there any way we can get notified which resource is being loaded?

**Something Like:**

```
window.onResourceLoad = function (e) {
   alert(e.URL);
}
```

Comment: You may be able to create a listener for added nodes with the [MutationObserver API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver). You would specify it to observe for `{ childList: true }`, then filter the DOM tree for images & scripts (and any other elements you are interested in), set a `loading` flag for each new element, and bind a `load` listener on those elements to remove the flag — however this is likely to be incredibly computationally expensive, full of quirks and only applicable to modern browsers.

Answer (score 0):

For JS please use jQuery getScript() function, Like this

```
$.getScript(URL, function(){
 /*Script loaded*/
 //APPLY ACTION HERE
})
```

For CSS, please load css from get function and append css in head

```
$.get(myStylesLocation, function(css)
{
   $('<style type="text/css"></style>')
      .html(css)
      .appendTo("head");
   /*CSS loaded */
   //APPLY ACTION HERE
});
```

Comment: Actually, I am not loading the resources, the browser is. I need to hook into an event where I get notified of when a resource start loading. The resource can be any css, js, img, font file etc

Comment: @asim-ishaq Resource Loading... or loaded?

Comment: At any point, before, after or during. But must notify for each of them.

Comment: @asim-ishaq You will need need to identify resource information custom,
You should use setTimeout to pull up resources information is ready or being loading... like JavaScript check function not undefined, for css (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744270/dynamically-loading-css?answertab=oldest#tab-top)
For image `document.getElementById('image_id').onload = func;`
This is only way.. if you comfort with.. good luck